# What makes LXD autostart?

Tags: snap, services, autostart, lxd

I can see that `snap` creates and enables a `snap.lxd.activate.service` service, that [runs](https://github.com/lxc/lxd-pkg-snap/blob/c786695/snapcraft/commands/daemon.activate#L108) `lxd activateifneeded`. But I don't see any signs of it in [`snapcraft.yml`](https://github.com/lxc/lxd-pkg-snap/blob/c786695f28377bf1d3caed76d51e844ed2911274/snapcraft.yaml#L61-L84). `snap.lxd.activate.service` is enabled and `snap.lxd.daemon.service` is static. What tells `snap` to do it this way? And what's misleading is that `snap services` somehow lists `lxd.daemon` as enabled.

On a side note, `activateifneeded` won't autostart the user daemon, right?

Comment: What is the version of the OS you are using?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 22.04